# Open node in Umbraco programmatically

Tags: umbraco

I have created a dashboard for an [Umbraco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbraco) site and I want to link from it to various node in the tree.

From what I can tell Umbraco uses editcontent.aspx?id={thenodeid} and javascript:opencontent({nodeid}).

Whenever I try to use these they always fail.

Does anyone know how to open a display a node in the Umbraco back end?

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail on what you are trying to do?

Are you trying to open a node in the content tree on the left or navigating to a node edit form in the right section of the screen?

Also how does it fail and what version of Umbraco are you using.

Comment: @Tim Saunders "Are you trying to open a node in the content tree on the left or navigating to a node edit form in the right section of the screen" this is exactly what i am trying to do.

When use editcontent.aspx?id={thenodeid} i get the error saying it cant find the node. I have checked and the node definetly exists.

When i use javascript method i just get an error saying the method does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Tim Saunders said you really just need to target the correct iframe. The openContent function looks like this:

```
function openContent(id) {
 parent.right.document.location.href = 'editContent.aspx?id=' + id;
}
```

So you need to target the 'right' iframe.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested editContent.aspx?id=1234 on my Umbraco installation and it seems to work correctly.

I'm assuming you are replacing {thenodeid} with the actual node id you want?

Umbraco uses iFrames in the backend for the content tree and the content areas etc. This means that you do not always have full access to the Javascript libraries from the frame that you are in.

Therefore you may need to either include the library in the page you are working with or try and reference the method calls by walking up the dom.

I can't find any documentation for this so it may be a case of looking at the HTML source and working out what is going on.